# (Python Unittest) Module being tested cannot import its dependencies: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, unit-testing, directory, python-import, importerror

I am working on developing unittests for a project that has been already completed, however I am having a hard time running my unittests without modifying the original code. The module I am trying to test has other dependencies in the same folder that will not import when the unittests are run. Here is what my directory looks like:

```
root
|--main_folder
   |--module1.py
   |--module2.py
|--tests
   |--test_module1.py
```

The original code in module1.py successfully imports module2.py on its own like this: `from module2 import Practices` where `Practices` is a function from `module2`.

The issue I am running into is that in order to run `test_module1.py` (which I am doing by calling `python3 -m unittest` from the root directory), I have to modify `module1.py` itself such that it says: `from main_folder.module2 import Practices`.

If I run the test file without modifying `module1.py`, I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'`.

Ideally I cannot modify the code in this way, and I am trying to find a way to make my tests work without touching the application itself. How should I go about this? `module1.py` runs normally when I run the application without modifying the file, however modifying it so that the tests work breaks the main application. What can I do to make my tests independent of the code for the main app?

*(For some more background, the `test_module1.py` file works by calling `from main_folder.module1 import fun1` where `fun1` is the function I am trying to test)*

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using MacOS Catalina v10.15.3.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your tests using one of the following commands (replacting the actual paths):

if your tests import the modules "from main_folder import ..."

```
env PYTHONPATH=/root python3 -m unittest
```

or if your tests import directly "import module1":

```
env PYTHONPATH=/root/main_folder python3 -m unittest
```

As a side note, you might need to have existing

```
 main_folder/__init__.py
```

file, to get the main_folder recognized as package, depending of the python version you're using. If you currently don't have such file, try creating it (empty, no need to put code inside it) and check if the issue persists.

Comment: I tried both commands and they worked when my "module1.py" document was still importing "module2.py" using `from main_folder.module2 import Practices`. However when I tried by taking out "main_folder" out of the import statement in "module1.py", neither `env PYTHONPATH` call worked, and I still got the same ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: you can try running with 'env PYTHONPATH=/root/main_folder:/root python3 -m unittest'  (this will add bot paths)

Comment: you also need to create main_folder/__init__.py file to get the 'main_folder' recognized as package